# Extract number from a column with text & number

Tags: r, dataframe, numbers, extract

I have a data frame column that looks like this:

Chr1
Chr14
Chr19
Chr2
Chr8
Chr7

I want to create a new column which looks as follows:
1
14
19
2
8
7

I tried this code, but it didn't work for me:
New$CHR_1 <- substr(OLD$CHR, 4, 4) %>% as.integer

Comment: ´substr(OLD$CHR, 4, nchar(OLD$CHR))´

Comment: Try: `substring(OLD$CHR, 4)` instead of `substr(OLD$CHR, 4, 4)`

Comment: It is just printing the output in my console. Can I make the changes in data frame itself? Thanks

Comment: `New$CHR_1 <- as.integer(substring(OLD$CHR, 4))`

Comment: object 'New' not found

Comment: `New <- data.frame(CHR_1 = as.integer(substring(OLD$CHR, 4)))`

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` i.e `dput(OLD)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `readr::parse_number` to extract the number from the column.

```
OLD <- data.frame(CHR = c("Chr1", "Chr14", "Chr19", "Chr2", "Chr8", "Chr7"))
OLD$num <- readr::parse_number(OLD$CHR)
OLD

#    CHR num
#1  Chr1   1
#2 Chr14  14
#3 Chr19  19
#4  Chr2   2
#5  Chr8   8
#6  Chr7   7
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a solution with the packages `data.table` and `stringr`. You just need to use the following lines of code:

**REPREX**

- Your data

```r
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

# Create your data.frame
OLD <- data.frame(CHR = c("Chr1", "Chr14", "Chr19", "Chr2", "Chr8", "Chr7"))
```

- Code

```r
# Convert into data.table
setDT(OLD)

# Add a column "Chr_ID" containing the numbers
OLD[ , Chr_ID := lapply(.SD, str_extract,"(?<=^Chr)\\d+"), .SDcols = "CHR"]
```

- Output

```r
OLD
#>      CHR Chr_ID
#> 1:  Chr1      1
#> 2: Chr14     14
#> 3: Chr19     19
#> 4:  Chr2      2
#> 5:  Chr8      8
#> 6:  Chr7      7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks again, but it again shows the output in console instead of modifying the df  :(

Comment: O.K. I edit my answer

Comment: @Mahan Did my edit finally solve your problem? If yes, please mark the answer as accepted to make it easier for other users to find the right answers. If not, please write what the problem is.

Comment: I tried your code - but I only see a new column with NAs - its an empty column!

Comment: Oh sorry. there was a typo in the regex part of the code. For your convenience, I have prepared a complete reprex for you to test. If this works for you as well, please consider accepting the answer. Cheers

Comment: I just rerun the code again and see the data.table: The new column has all NAs

Comment: That's a bit weird. In theory the reprex guarantees the reproducibility of the code. Could you please copy-paste the line of code you are using.

Comment: ! I used exactly the same code you provided but seems it didn't work for me. But thank you so much for your help.

Comment: O.K. sorry I couldn't help you better and glad to see that the solution proposed by Ronak works for you. That said, I'm still wondering why the code I suggested works on my computer and not on yours.